# 10 Предложений по стилистике

Tags: стилистика

Помогите составить 10 предложений словосочетаемости....пример:Преклонил колено,но не склонил голову

Comment: Не могли бы Вы чётче сформировать задание.

Answer (score 6):

Например, такие:Он был НИЗвергнут с пьедестала и ОТвергнут всеми.

ВОСславили в веках за то,что ПРОславил возможности человека.

БЕЗвинно пострадал, чтобы спасти сотни НЕвинных людей.

ИЗбрал свой путь, когда ВЫбрал профессию

ПРЕтерпел всяческие лишения за то, что не Стерпел унижение достоинства.

Замысел его ПРЕтворился в жизнь, а сам он РАСтворился в общей жизни.

Лицо старика ПРЕобразилось  и на нём ОТОбразился восторг.

Что НИСпошлёт тебе судьбина,какого ещё врага ПОДОшлёт?

Comment: Славно... Я бы даже не сообразил, о чем вообще просят.

Comment: Розкрився купол парашута,
И большелап почухав вниз,
Як пограничник Карацупа,
Не дав ворогам шанс на *жисть*.